# MySQL Sorting Error in EAV Table

Tags: mysql

I have an entity attribute model for storing information related to users. I am also then trying to sort a particular entity which only contains numbers in decreasing order. I am running a query such as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_meta` WHERE `key` = 'children'   ORDER BY `user_meta`.`value`  DESC
```

I had not run into problems with this query until recently when a user had 11 `children` and now the results look as follows

```
+-----+----------+-------+
| uid | key      | value |
+-----+----------+-------+
|  1  | children | 5     |
|  1  | children | 3     |
|  1  | children | 3     |
|  1  | children | 2     |
|  1  | children | 11    |
|  1  | children | 1     |
+-----+----------+-------+
```

I have tried various different modifications of this query but have not found anything fixing this ranking problem where 5 > 11. It might be of use but both the `key` and `value` attributes are `varchar(250)` if that affects the sorting algorithm that MySQL uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your column is a `CHAR` type. It compares the strings rather than the numbers.

You could cast it when ordering:

```
ORDER BY CAST(`user_meta`.`value` AS UNSIGNED)
```

Or for signed integers:

```
ORDER BY CAST(`user_meta`.`value` AS SIGNED)
```

See also: [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)